# ngFor with index as value in attribute

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a simple `ngFor` loop which also keeps track of the current `index`. I want to store that `index` value in an attribute so I can print it. But I can't figure out how this works.

I basically have this:

```
<ul *ngFor="#item of items; #i = index" data-index="#i">
    <li>{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

I want to store the value of `#i` in the attribute `data-index`. I tried several methods but none of them worked.

I have a demo here: http://plnkr.co/edit/EXpOKAEIFlI9QwuRcZqp?p=preview

How can I store the `index` value in the `data-index` attribute?

Comment: Just a note - with the `*ngFor` on the `UL` as in this question, this would repeat the `UL` for each item, not the `LI`

Answer (score 1566, accepted):

In Angular Version 17+ using built in control flow:

```
<ul>
  @for (item of items; track item; let  i = $index) {    
    <li>
        {{i+1}} {{item}}
    </li>
    }
</ul>
```

In Angular Version 5+:

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items; index as i">
    {{i+1}} {{item}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

I would use this syntax to set the index value into an attribute of the HTML element:

#### Angular 2-4

You have to use `let` to declare the value rather than `#`.

```html
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
        {{item}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### AngularJS

```html
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="#item of items; #i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
        {{item}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/LiCeyKGUapS5JKkRWnUJ?p=preview.

Comment: Just for curiosity, why `[attr['data-index']]=i
` would not work, where as it evaluate as same

Comment: In fact, the `attr.` is a syntax to tell Angular2 to set the value of the expression to the attribute name. It's not just like evaluating JSON, I guess ;-) See this link: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html

Comment: I rolled back the recent edit in order to have both the original answer and the new updated code value.  I was searching for some early beta stuff and saw that this answer was modified, so it no longer applied to the beta version of angular 2.

Comment: UPDATE: 08/2017 <div *ngFor="let hero of heroes; let i=index; trackBy: trackById" >

Comment: as of  Oct 17, 2018 Angular 6 is using *ngFor="let item of items; index as i" See Leo's answer below.

Comment: Angular 1.x (known as AngularJS as opposed to Angular) doesn't use `*nfFor` structural directive at all. On the old version you would `ng-repeat="item in items"` and then access provided variables within the template as `$index, $even, $odd...` [See the docs yourself.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Answer (score 491):

In Angular 5/6/7/8:

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items; index as i">
    {{i+1}} {{item}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

In older versions

```html
<ul *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
  <li>{{i+1}} {{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

---

Angular.io ▸ API ▸ NgForOf

- [Description](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#description)
- [Local variables](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables)

Unit test examples

- [ng_for_spec.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/test/directives/ng_for_spec.ts)

Another interesting example

- [Grouping](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngfor/#_grouping)

Comment: `index as i` works great, thank you. But isn't the `*ngFor` meant to go on the element to be repeated (e.g. the `<li>` in this case)? The code you suggested creates multiple `<ul>`s rathers than multiple `<li>`s.

Comment: `index as i` is more elegant than `let i = index`

Answer (score 126):

Just an update to this, Thierry's answer is still correct, but there has been an update to Angular2 with regards to:

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
  <li>{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

The `#i = index` should now be `let i = index`

EDIT/UPDATE:

The `*ngFor` should be on the element you're wanting to foreach, so for this example it should be:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

EDIT/UPDATE

Angular 5

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items; index as i" [attr.data-index]="i">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

EDIIT/UPDATE

Angular 7/8

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of items; index as i">
  <li [attr.data-index]="i">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: And `#item` should be `let item` ;-)

Comment: Just a note - with the `*ngFor` on the `UL` as in this answer (except the Angular 5 update), this would repeat the `UL` for each item, not the `LI`

Answer (score 55):

I think its already been answered before, but just a correction if you are populating an unordered list, the `*ngFor` will come in the element which you want to repeat. So it should be insdide `<li>`. Also, Angular2 now uses let to declare a variable.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">     
               {{item}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think that it is best practice to specify the *ngFor directive in ul tag                                                                                                     
 <ul *ngFor="let item of items; index as i" [attr.data-index]="i">
    <li >     
               {{item}}
    </li>
</ul>

Comment: If you specify ngFor in the ul tag, then the entity that will be repeated will be ul, but here u dont want to repeat the ul, you just want to iterate on the list elements i.e. li.

Comment: @monica is correct here, the `*ngFor` goes on the element to be repeated, so the original question as written would get a lot of `UL` elements, each with a single `LI`.

Answer (score 35):

Adding this late answer to show a case most people will come across. If you only need to see what is the last item in the list, use the `last` key word:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of devcaseFeedback.reviewItems; let last = last">
  <divider *ngIf="!last"></divider>
</div>
```

This will add the divider component to every item except the last.

Because of the comment below, I will add the rest of the `ngFor` exported values that can be aliased to local variables (As are [shown in the docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables)):

- **$implicit: T**: The value of the individual items in the iterable
  (ngForOf).
- **ngForOf: NgIterable**: The value of the iterable expression. Useful when the expression is more complex then a property access, for example when using the async pipe (userStreams | async).
- **index: number**: The index of the current item in the iterable.
- **count: number**: The length of the iterable.
- **first: boolean**: True when the item is the first item in the iterable.
- **last: boolean**: True when the item is the last item in the iterable.
- **even: boolean**: True when the item has an even index in the iterable.
- **odd: boolean**: True when the item has an odd index in the iterable.

Comment: How do you know this? Is there some kind of documentation somewhere, or a typescript file, or something that lists all the keywords we can use?

Comment: Damn. I was hoping to find a similar list for Angular Material's tables by browsing through the .ts files, or something. The documentation for Material Tables is a lot, lot worse.

Comment: It is in common.d.ts in angular/common thats where ngFor comes from

Comment: Link to docs: https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables

Answer (score 23):

The other answers are correct but you can omit the `[attr.data-index]` altogether and just use

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">{{i + 1}}</li>
</ul
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use **[attr.data-index]** directly to save the index to data-index attribute which is available in Angular versions 2 and above.

```
    <ul*ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
         <li>{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 9):

with laravel pagination

```
file.component.ts file

    datasource: any = {
        data: []
    }

    loadData() {
        this.service.find(this.params).subscribe((res: any) => {
            this.datasource = res;
        });
    }

html file

   <tr *ngFor="let item of datasource.data; let i = index">
       <th>{{ datasource.from + i }}</th>
   </tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<div *ngFor="let piece of allPieces; let i=index">
{{i}} // this will give index
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**In Angular 17+**

You can use the new syntax:

```
@for (item of items; track item.id; let idx = $index) {
  {{idx}} - {{item}}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Get API call

```
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root',
    })
    export class ApiService {

      private readonly postsSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
      readonly postsResult$ = this.postsSubject.asObservable();

      get postsResult(): any {
        return this.postsSubject.getValue();
      }
      set postsResult(posts: any) {
        this.postsSubject.next(gifRes);
      }
    
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
        getSearchResult(): Observable<any> {
            this.postsResult = this.http.get<any>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
          }
}
```

For getting index of postResult

```
<div *ngFor="let post of apiService.postsResult$ | async; let i = index">
{{i}} - {{post.title}}
<div>
```