# how to set Index for angular2

Tags: angular

```
 <template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="faculytLectureMaster"  >
        <tr *ngIf="item.subjectname != 'Break' && item.facultyname != 'NA'" (click)="OnLectureClick(item,0)" 
             [class.selected]="item === _selectedHero" >
            <td> **set Index number here** </td>
            <td>{{item.lectstart}}-{{item.lectend}}</td>                
            <td>{{item.facultyname}}</td>
            <td>{{item.subjectname}}({{item.subjectcode}})</td>             
            <td>{{item.attendtotal}}</td>
            <td>{{item.present}}</td>
            <td>{{item.absent}}</td>
            <td>{{item.section}}</td>
        </tr>
    </template>
```

I want to set Index for this template in `angular2` like `$Index` in `angular1`

I searched I got solutions like  `*ngFor="let item of  _studentList let i=index"`  which work for normal but in template how to use?

how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ngFor with index as value in attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405618/ngfor-with-index-as-value-in-attribute)

Comment: I used but in my case I use template its not working   I tried like **[ngForOf]="faculytLectureMaster let i = index" **  but not showing output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define index like `let-i=index`, in this case in your ngFor, you could print the index with: `{{i}}`

Try this one, should work:

```
 <template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="faculytLectureMaster" let-i="index" >
        <tr *ngIf="item.subjectname != 'Break' && item.facultyname != 'NA'" (click)="OnLectureClick(item,0)" 
             [class.selected]="item === _selectedHero" >
            <td>{{i}}</td>
            <td>{{item.lectstart}}-{{item.lectend}}</td>                
            <td>{{item.facultyname}}</td>
            <td>{{item.subjectname}}({{item.subjectcode}})</td>             
            <td>{{item.attendtotal}}</td>
            <td>{{item.present}}</td>
            <td>{{item.absent}}</td>
            <td>{{item.section}}</td>
        </tr>
    </template>
```

**More info [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html)**

Comment: how to use  **[ngForOf]="faculytLectureMaster"** here

Comment: Updated answer :)

Comment: showing error like  **Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token = at column 37 in [let item of facultyLectureMaster; i = index]**

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my bad... it should be `let` in front of `i` as well: `<template *ngFor="let item of facultyLectureMaster; let i = index">` Sorry about that!

Comment: @Pravin I updated my answer, just now noticed you wanted ngForOf specifically! :)

Comment: it work fine  but problem it calculate hidden row because this **ngIf="item.subjectname != 'Break' && item.facultyname != 'NA'"** condition