# ngFor custom index increment Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngfor

How can I use custom index increment or decrement in ngFor?
I want something like this:

```
`<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
   <span>
     {{items[i].name}}
  </span>
  <span>
     {{items[i+1].name}}
  </span>
  <!-- Then I want to increment index value like i++ -->
 </div>`
```

I mean how can I use custom for loop in angular's component html file?

Comment: What do you mean by custom index?

Comment: In ngFor, index increase by 1 and return next item but I want to increase the index by 2 or any other value. So I can use i and i+1(1st and 2nd item) in the first iteration and increase the index value i=i+2 then in next iteration I will get the 3rd and 4th item because i=2 and so on

Comment: Below question might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54821472/how-to-increment-and-update-index-value-by-2-in-ngfor-while-using-a-fixed-struct#:~:text=Duplicate%20of%20ngFor%20with%20index,in%20a%202%20column%20structure.

Comment: Actually you want two items per ngFor iteration. here is the answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36376185/7005503

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to achieve is something like:

```
<div>
  <span *ngFor="let item of items">
    {{item.name}}
  </span>
</div>
```

This way you don't have to increment anything - angular ngFor directive does it for you

**Update** I'm not sure what do you want to achieve - maybe try to describe it in a better way. Maybe try this:

```
<div>
 <p *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
  <span>{{item.name}}</span>
  <span>{{items[i + 1].name}}</span>
 </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I know that But this way one item iterates in each iteration but I want 2 items in each iteration like 1st and 2nd item in 1st iteration, 3rd and 4th in 2nd iteration....