# Angular mat tree on matTreeNodeDef iteration not able to get index as of ngfor

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an angular material tree. On which i have a code like below

```
<mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; let idx=index">
  {{node.filename}}::{{idx}}
</mat-tree-node>
```

Here idx not populating

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47635574/9839191
Maybe this answer will help

Comment: @Oram no it won't. I have tried it.

Comment: I have the same issue, any help ?

Comment: hi Bro, Have u got any good Solution for this. ?

Comment: @DineshKanivu Do you want to get index at each level?

Comment: what type of tree do you use: flat or nested?

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid `*matTreeNodeDef` is not same as `*ngFor` directive.

`*matTreeNodeDef` directive accepts 2 Inputs.

First being `TreeNode<T>` which can be defined as

```
<mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node">
  ...
</mat-tree-node>
```

where `node` represents the TreeNode object.

Second being `matTreeNodeDefWhen` which is a function to filter the Tree nodes and can be defined as

HTML

```
<mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when hasChild">
  ...
</mat-tree-node>
```

TS

```
hasChild = (_: number, node: FlatNode) => node.expandable;  // returns a boolean value
```

Generally speaking, a tree structure does not have an index.

Reference: https://material.angular.io/components/tree/api#MatTreeNodeDef

Answer (score 1):

you will need to add index to the node with a transform function like: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57142368/11692089

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not populating because you are not iterating. The `let node;` only declares node as the data source. Try `let node of nodes` or `ngFor="let node of node; index as idx"`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the task, the [css counters](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_counters.asp) could be a solution