# getting index of value from Array iterated in dropdown Box

Tags: angular, angular8

I am working in Angular where I am facing problem in

**getting index of value from Array iterated in dropdown Box**

I am sharing my code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  fruit =  [{"id" : 123 , "name" : "Apple" } , {"id" : 124 , "name" : "Orange" } ]

  constructor(){}

  getRsId(value , Index){}
}
```

html

```
<select (ngModelChange)="getRsId($event , i)">
  <option [value]='data.emp_code' *ngFor='let data of fruit ; let i = index' > {{data.name}} </option>
</select>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p6deib?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: not understand your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ngFor with index as value in attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405618/ngfor-with-index-as-value-in-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this :

```html
<select (change)="getRsId($event)">
  <option [value]='data.emp_code' *ngFor='let data of fruit ; let i = index' > {{data.name}} </option>
</select>
```

```js
 getRsId(value){
   console.log(value);
   console.log(value.target['selectedIndex']);
  }
```

Here is demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-luhanl?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I am getting error : Cannot read property 'selectedIndex' of undefined

Comment: check demo its working there. Open console check index value.