# How to get index in an angular loop?

Tags: javascript, angular

Hello I have this loop in angular in need to find the index of post so I can delete it?
`*ngFor="let post of posts"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ngFor with index as value in attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405618/ngfor-with-index-as-value-in-attribute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use index

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
  {{i}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple [local variables](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables) in the `*ngFor` directive one of which is `index`.

```html
<div *ngFor="let post of posts; let i=index">
  {{ i }}
</div>
```

Also almost all the punctuation in the syntax are optional. The semi-colon isn't mandatory.

```html
<div *ngFor="let post of posts let i=index let even=even let odd=odd">
  {{ i }}
</div>
```