# How can I check whether the last item of *ngFor is displayed and then call a function?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I want to call a function, when the last item is about to be displayed.

```
<div *ngFor="let el of arr">
   {{ el }}
<div>
```

`arr` is defined as

```
public arr = [1,2,3,4];
```

How could I call a funtion after the last item is about to be displayed?

This would be interesting for large data structures with thousands of elements.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35405648/13258211

Comment: I want to call a function just once after all items have been displayed. This would not work for me

Comment: Please use index in ngFor.
*ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" 
you can calculate the length of arr. than compare it with index, once you have the length-1 equal to index than call your expected method.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. You could maybe use `onload` together with the index to fire a function when the last element in the array has loaded.

Comment: Hey Mike, ```onload``` does not work on ```div```