# Angular ngFor without the let item of items syntax

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I am new to Angular and just wanted to understand if I can use the ngFor directive without the let item of items; let i = index syntax

Is there any other way of getting hold of the index while iterating an array when using ngFor

My Sample App

```
<div *ngFor="let oddNumber of oddNumbers; let i = index">
   <app-odd *ngIf="oddNumbers[i]" [number]="oddNumbers[i]"></app-odd>
   <app-even *ngIf="evenNumbers[i]" [number]="evenNumbers[i]"></app-even>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Internally the micro-syntax [`*ngFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#description) is expanded to the usual binding syntax `[ngForOf]`.

Eg.

```html
<div *ngFor="let oddNumber of oddNumbers; let i = index">
  ...
</div>
```

is expanded to

```html
<ng-template ngFor let-oddNumber [ngForOf]="oddNumbers" let-i="index">
  <div>...</div>
</ng-template>
```

Without the `let oddNumber of oddNumbers`, the `let-i="index"` doesn't have any context. So it isn't possible to use the `*ngFor` directive without the `let oddNumber of oddNumbers` input.

However if you wish to access only the odd or even items in the loop, `*ngFor` has boolean local variables like `odd` and `even` similar to `index`.

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index; let even=even; let odd=odd">
  <ng-container *ngIf="even">
    <!-- item in even position -->
    ...
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="odd">
    <!-- item in odd position -->
    ...
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is the right way to save the index of each array item in the HTML file: [ngFor with index as value in attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405618/ngfor-with-index-as-value-in-attribute)

But if you are looking for other ways to save the index, you can try to iterate through the array in the Ts file and then do the desired action based on the index number.