# Adding a new column in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have:

```
export class Column {
constructor(public name: string, public tasks: string[]) {} }
```

and

```
import { Column } from './column.model';

export class Board {
constructor(public name: string, public columns: Column[]) {}}
```

Here is my typescript code:

```
     import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray, transferArrayItem } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
    import { Board } from 'src/app/models/board.model';
    import { Column } from 'src/app/models/column.model';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-main-view',
      templateUrl: './main-view.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./main-view.component.scss']
    })
    export class MainViewComponent implements OnInit {
    newcolumn: string;
      constructor() { }
    
      board: Board = new Board('Test Board', [
        new Column('First', [
          "one",
          "two"
        ])
      ]);
    
      ngOnInit() {
      }
    
      drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
        if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
          moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
        } else {
          transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
            event.container.data,
            event.previousIndex,
            event.currentIndex);
        }
      }
  addColumn() {
    this.board.columns.push(this.newcolumn);
  }
    
    }
```

Error: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Column[]

I have trouble with adding a function that adds a new column to my board.
There is also a bug when using board.column.name. Please help. I've been trying to do this for several hours.

Comment: I don't know your model but here are the things that I find weird : 1) `newcolumn` is declared as a `string` but you are using it as if it was a `Column`.  2) `board.column.name` does not make sense to me. The board might have multiple columns so something like this seems more logical : `board.columns[0].name`

Comment: code for Board and Column are in my post. Everything here, but without the addColumn function: https://github.com/Devstackr/kanban-angular-layout

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle check my com

Comment: `this.board.columns` is a `Column[]` and `this.newcolumn` is a `string` so it does not make sense to write `this.board.columns.push(this.newcolumn);`. Something like `this.board.columns.push(new Column('Name', []));` should be fine.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle thanks :) Do you have any idea for adding a task to an existing column?

Comment: In your model, a task is a `string`. So you can take the column you want and add a task. `board.columns[0].tasks.push('Test')`.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle okay, but can i skip typing the column id and automatically get this ?

Comment: `board.columns` is an array of columns so you have to tell on which one you want to add the task. But if you want to add the tasks on the column you just created, you can also do it like this : `const column = new Column('Name', []); column.tasks.push('Yolo'); this.board.columns.push(column)`;

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle In my project, a button activates addColumn and another button activates addTask. I would like to create adding tasks to specific columns.

Comment: You have to use the index of the column. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405618/ngfor-with-index-as-value-in-attribute#answer-35405648) to see how to get the index. The important part is `let i = index`

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle thank you very much :)