# How can I populate the dropdown values for each row within a data table?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, primeng

The following is my HTML.

```
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Test Data
                </th>
                <th>
                    Test Data Options
                </th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ng-container>
                       {{data.testData}}
                    </ng-container>
                </td>
                <td class="text-base font-normal">
                    <ng-container>
                        <p-dropdown [options]="dropdownOptions" placeholder="Select Test Data"></p-dropdown>
                    </ng-container>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

This is my JSON file.

```
“data”: [ 
          { 
            “testData”: “Test Data A”, 
            “testDataOptions”: [ 
                                 {  
                                   “testDataOptionValue”: “Test Data A1 Option”,     
                                   “testDataOptionLabel”: “Test Data A1” 
                                 }, 
                                 {  
                                   “testDataOptionValue”: “Test Data A2 Option”,     
                                   “testDataOptionLabel”: “Test Data A2” 
                                 } 
                               ], 
          }, 
          { 
            “testData”: “Test Data B”,
            “testDataOptions”: [ 
                                 {  
                                   “testDataOptionValue”: “Test Data B1 Option”,    
                                   “testDataOptionLabel”: “Test Data B1” 
                                 }, 
                                 {  
                                   “testDataOptionValue”: “Test Data B2 Option”,    
                                   “testDataOptionLabel”: “Test Data B2” 
                                 } 
                               ], 
          }
```

How could I populate the dropdown values in each row in the data table according to their indexes?

For example

> The Test Data A row dropdown values should be:
> **Test Data A1, Test Data A2**
>
> The Test Data B row dropdown values should be:
> **Test Data B1, Test Data B2**

[image: Sample Screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *guess* you're missing a `*ngFor` in the code snippet you sent:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let data of json.data">
  <td>{{ data.testData }}</td>
  <td>
    <p-dropdown [options]="data.testDataOptions" optionLabel="testDataOptionLabel" optionValue="testDataOptionValue"></p-dropdown>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**Edit: binding the selected value**

A first option, although it might feel hacky depending on context, is to bind to the data object you already have. For instance:

```html
<p-dropdown [options]="data.testDataOptions" optionLabel="testDataOptionLabel" optionValue="testDataOptionValue" [(ngModel)]="data.selectedValue"></p-dropdown>
```

If that feels weird or you just don't want to mess with that data, then you'll need to store it in a separate variable, which can be an array or a key/value structure. Then you just bind each item to the corresponding entry in the the data structure.

Comment: Hello thank you for the enlightenment what should I be doing if I would want to store the selected option on all the rows since they wouldn't be able to share the same `NgModel` and pass it in a JSON data?

Comment: You're welcome. I edited my answer with possible solutions for your problem.

Comment: If the `ngModel` is data.selectedValue does that mean for my original JSON data I need to have a `selectedValue` within the `testDataOptions` so that I can replace it? In the case if I were to use a separate variable such as an array how would I be able to bind each of the data element item into the corresponding entry in the data structure?

Comment: Get the index of the current element (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405618/ngfor-with-index-as-value-in-attribute) and the bind to `selectedValues[i]`

Answer (score 2):

Allan gave you the correct answer, I'm just going to expand it a bit. Since your dropdown options list might be a large one, please consider using `trackBy` as well. It is not mandatory and it does not always prove much more performant, but overall it should help with performance. You can do it like so:

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of json.data; trackBy: trackByMethod">
  <td>{{ data.testData }}</td>
  <td>
    <p-dropdown [options]="data.testDataOptions" optionLabel="testDataOptionLabel" optionValue="testDataOptionValue"></p-dropdown>
  </td>
</tr>
```

While in your `.ts` file (make sure you add some IDs to your items as well - or use other unique identifiers):

```
trackByMethod = (index: number, item: any): string => item.id;
```

You can read more about `trackBy` here: https://dev.to/rfornal/angular-is-trackby-necessary-with-ngfor-594e

Comment: Hello thank you I will take a look at how this `trackBy` works